# Pivot Table Filter By Date - Error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to filter my PIVOT TABLE by Date but I keep getting same error: "Error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error" and it points out at this part of the code:

```
.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=CLng(startDate), Value2:=CLng(endDate)
```

I put the IF statement to make sure that the date format is correct, but I keep getting the "Error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error"
(The format is okey)

This is what I have in C2 and C3

[image]

And this is what I have in the data with which I created the pivot table.

[image]

Picture of my pivot table:

[image]

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()

Some Code...


 ' Define start and end dates from the "Deporte" worksheet
    Dim startDate As Variant
    Dim endDate As Variant
    startDate = ws_Dest.Range("C2")
    endDate = ws_Dest.Range("C3")

    If IsDate(startDate) And IsDate(endDate) Then

        ' Apply the date filter
        With ptTable.PivotFields("Fecha Desde") ' Ensure this is the correct field name
            .ClearAllFilters ' Clear any existing filters
            .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=CLng(startDate), Value2:=CLng(endDate)
        End With

    Else
        MsgBox "The start date or end date is not a valid date."
    End If

    ' Refresh the PivotTable to apply the date filter
    ptTable.RefreshTable

End sub
```

Here is a table generated:

| Fecha Desde | SKU | Ventas | Division |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29-01-2024 | mpm23958 | 3000 | Deporte |  |  |
| 05-02-2024 | mpm38754 | 2000 | Regalos |  |  |
| 19-02-2024 | mpm48832 | 4000 | Deporte |  |  |
| 29-01-2024 | mpm38784 | 300 | Deporte |  |  |
| 19-02-2024 | mpm28494 | 500 | Deporte |  |  |

Comment: Exactly what values are in C2/C3 ?

Comment: I've tested the code w/o issue on M365. Please share sample data and screenshot of pvt.  
Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Working solution here: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/datebetween-change-from-a-date-to-a-value-from-a-cell.1158062/

Comment: There is the table and added picture of the pivot table as well.

| Fecha Desde  | Ventas             | Division  |    |    |
|------------- |------------------- |---------- |--- |--- |
| 29-01-2024   | 3000               | Deporte   |    |    |
| 05-02-2024   |              2000  | Regalos   |    |    |
| 19-02-2024   | 4000               | Deporte   |    |    |
| 29-01-2024   |              300   | Deporte   |    |    |
| 19-02-2024   |              500   | Deporte   |    |    |

Comment: @taller you think you can help me with the new info?

Comment: @williams, tried the solution with .text and add2, but still not having results. Think you could help me with the new info provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Looping through `PivotItems` to filter the expected date range

```vb
Sub FilterPivotTable()
 ' Define start and end dates from the "Deporte" worksheet
    Dim startDate As Variant
    Dim endDate As Variant
    Dim pvtItem As PivotItem, iVal As Long
    Dim ws_Dest: Set ws_Dest = ActiveSheet ' for testing
    Dim ptTable: Set ptTable = ws_Dest.PivotTables(1) ' for testing
    startDate = ws_Dest.Range("C2")
    endDate = ws_Dest.Range("C3")
    If IsDate(startDate) And IsDate(endDate) Then
        startDate = CLng(startDate)
        endDate = CLng(endDate)
        ' Apply the date filter
        With ptTable.PivotFields("Fecha Desde") ' Ensure this is the correct field name
            For Each pvtItem In .PivotItems
                iVal = CLng(CDate(pvtItem.Value))
                pvtItem.Visible = (iVal >= startDate And iVal <= endDate)
            Next
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "The start date or end date is not a valid date."
    End If
    ' Refresh the PivotTable to apply the date filter
    ptTable.RefreshTable
End Sub
```

---

> Question: For example: Start Date is 01/01/2024 and endDat is 24/03/2024. But its not filtering 08/01/2024. Why do you think this happens or what do you recomend I do?

- Excel think `08/01/2024` is `2024 Aug 01` instead of `2024 Jan 08`. Below code proves it.
- If you have to use `dd/MMM/yyyy` on date column, you can use a UDF to convert a date string to its value.
- Replace `CLng(CDate(..))` and `CLng(..)` to `Date2Lng(..)` in `FilterPivotTable()`.

```vb
Function Date2Lng(ByVal sDate As String) As Long
    Dim aTxt
    aTxt = Split(sDate, "/")
    If UBound(aTxt) = 2 Then
        Date2Lng = CLng(VBA.DateSerial(aTxt(2), aTxt(1), aTxt(0)))
    Else
        Date2Lng = 0
    End If
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim sDay As String: sDay = "08/01/2024"
    Debug.Print Format(sDay, "yyyy MMM dd")
    Debug.Print CLng(CDate(sDay))
    Debug.Print Date2Lng(sDay)
    Debug.Print Format(Date2Lng(sDay), "yyyy MMM dd")
End Sub
```

***Output:***

```
2024 Aug 01
 45505 
 45299 
2024 Jan 08
```

Comment: Hey @Taller  your code works great but is leaving some dates a side.
For example:  Start Date is 01/01/2024 and endDat is 24/03/2024.
But its not filtering 08/01/2024. Why do you think this happens or what do you recomend I do?

Comment: Thnak you once again! works great